# Get a screenshot of custom layout

Tags: android, opencv

How do I take a screenshot of a custom layout from opencv? Is this code getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView() applicable with this custom view from opencv; get the bitmap out of it?

```
 <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/activity_java_surface_view"
    opencv:show_fps="true"
    opencv:camera_id="any" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this code work?

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: Actually I have tried that, but the output is black this is the [image](https://i.imgsafe.org/4ea2261057.png) as you can see it can detect imageButton which is not included in the xml but not the layout of JavaCameraview.